# Is there a safe interface to raw sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, rust

[Here](https://github.com/mcpherrinm/rust-traceroute) it is said that the only way is to use libc:

```
extern crate libc;
extern crate native;
use libc::{c_int, c_void, socket, AF_INET, sockaddr_storage};
use native::io::net::sockaddr_to_addr;
use std::io::net::ip::SocketAddr;
static SOCK_RAW: c_int = 3;
static IPPROTO_ICMP: c_int = 1;

fn recvfrom<'buf>(sock: c_int, buf: &'buf mut [u8]) -> (&'buf mut [u8], SocketAddr) {
  let mut storage: sockaddr_storage = unsafe { std::mem::init() };
  let storagep = &mut storage as *mut _ as *mut libc::sockaddr;
  let mut addrlen = std::mem::size_of::<libc::sockaddr_storage>() as libc::socklen_t;

  let bytes = unsafe { libc::recvfrom(sock,
                 buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void,
                 buf.len() as u64, 
                 0, storagep, &mut addrlen) };

  (buf.mut_slice_to(bytes as uint),
   sockaddr_to_addr(&storage, addrlen as uint).unwrap())
}

fn main() {
  let handle = unsafe { socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) };
  println!("{}", handle);
  let mut bufferator = [0, ..2048];
  loop {
    let (buf, from) = recvfrom(handle, bufferator.as_mut_slice());
    println!("from {}, data:\n{}", from, buf);
  }
}
```

but this was written a year ago, so things may be have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there cannot be a safe interface to arbitrary C code as C code cannot be guaranteed to not do things that safe Rust disallows. Although simply convention, many things in Rust land that say "raw" in the name have unsafe semantics.

What you can do is wrap the raw C code with Rust code that ensures that the C code never gets into a state that violates the safety of the program. That's how items like [`TcpStream`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) or [`UdpSocket`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) are constructed. There is no wrapper for ICMP sockets as far as I know.

Comment: One more question. The code above is old, so I'm converting it to be compatible with recent Rust version. Now, I don't know what to do with 'src/main.rs:3:5: 3:31 error: unresolved import `std::net::sockaddr_to_addr`. There is no `sockaddr_to_addr` in `std::net` [E0432]' I've searched http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=sockaddr_to_addr and could not find it. Is is being completely removed? If so, what do I have to use instead of?